# Windows 10 xbox game bar not recognizing game, and will not open

Tags: windows-10, age-of-empires, xbox-game-bar

I'm playing Age of Empires 1 on Windows 10. When I press win+G, I get a dialog saying "do you want to open the game bar?" and a single button saying "yes, this is a game". I click it, and nothing happens. If I press win+G again, the same dialog appears again, same as before.

Interestingly, this problem *only* appears on the retail version of vanilla AoE1. If I play the retail version with the Rise of Rome expansion, the game is recognized fine (when I begin the game, there's a dialog that says "press win+G to capture"), and if I press win+G, the game bar appears fine.

Further, the game bar works fine for both the trial versions of AoE1 and RoR. Out of the four possibilities (trial/retail and vanilla/expansion), only retail+vanilla isn't recognized by the game bar. The other three are fine.

I also tried just directly recording by pressing Win+alt+r, and again does works fine for the other three, but does nothing in vanilla retail AoE1.

I've tried adding the AoE1 retail vanilla executable to my games list in the Xbox app in windows 10, but that didn't do anything.

(I also considered using OBS, but there's another issue there with a black screen appearing whenever using game capture mode; that's a well-known issue, but all the pages I found that claim to solve it are for Nvidia GPUs; I have intel integrated graphics.) Either way, I would prefer a solution that can get the game bar to appear on my vanilla AoE retail game, especially since it appears just fine on the other 3 versions of the game listed.